# Why has this menu replaced the normal one in Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, context-menu

Eclipse is showing an odd short menu in place of the normal one when I right-click on a project (or anywhere) in the Package Explorer pane in Eclipse 3.7.1.

Normally I see a big context menu with a boatload of options, including "New", "Copy", "Paste", "Import", "Export", "Run as" etc. A few hours ago, something changed and now a right click brings up only the menu shown in the attached image.

Of course, "it used to work fine" - I didn't upgrade Eclipse, monkey with user preferences, or do anything else that might explain this.  Maybe I (or the cat) clicked something accidentally.

How to get rid of this menu, and what is it for anyway?[image: Strange new context menu in Eclipse Package Explorer]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall, delete folders, and reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to comment instead of answering, because I'm not sure my answer is correct as I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Anyway, I suggest you make sure you choose the correct perspective

```
Window->Open Perspective
```

And then try to reset the perspective:

```
Window->Reset Perspective
```

Comment: @darenw, Can you confirm if this worked for you or not?

Comment: That wasn't it.  The problem did go away eventually, after I accidently clicked something else.